# mix c and assembly cortex-m0

Tags: c, assembly, arm, cortex-m

I want write a routine for cortex-m0 in GCC C where mix C and assembly code. I am trying something like this

```
__attribute__((naked)) uint8_t dummy(uint8_t value)
{
    asm volatile (
            "push   {r1-r7, lr}\n\t"
             // R0 contains input value
             //here i do some operation on registers r0..r7         
             //.....
             //I guess result will be in the R0 register
            "MOV R0, R3\n\t"

            "pop    {r1-r7, pc}\n\t"
        );
}
```

but unfortunately i have problems:

- my program crashes because of this.
- compiler claims that my "dummy" routine doesn't have return value

EDIT, WORKING CODE:I moved the code to the separate .s file and final solution looks like this

```
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv6-m
    .text
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .align 1
    .globl    dummymethod
    .type    dummymethod, %function
dummymethod:
    .fnstart
            PUSH    {r1-r7, lr}
            // here some operation on registers R0..R7

            MOV R0, R3 //result is in R0

            pop {r1-r7, pc}

    .pool
    .cantunwind
    .fnend
    .size   dummymethod,.-dummymethod
```

Comment: It is generally a good idea to avoid inline assembly for that.  Put your routine into an assembly file and assemble it into an object file on its own.

Comment: For what you shoud the code should work fine. It compiles fine on my machine. If there's a problem it's probably somewhere else.

Comment: Also, add the output of `gcc -v`.

Comment: you dont have a return value that is why it is complaining, the inline assembly functionality including return is not recognized by the compiler so it doesnt see a return value (in C language).  add any return value return 0; and that should go away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use real assembly

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb
.globl dummy
.thumb_func
dummy:
    mov r0,r3
    bx lr
```

the calling convention allows for modification of r0-r3, return in r0, you are not touching r4,r5,r6,r7,lr so no need to push those.

ugly but you can assemble it with gcc, gnu assembler, as, is preferred (arm-whatever-as)

Comment: Might need a `.type dummy, #function` to link correctly.

Comment: i moved the code to a separate .s file and now it seems working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Falling off the end of a `naked` function is not actually an error.  Warning in that case was a GCC bug that was fixed somewhere before GCC 5.4.  (But code-gen is the same; older GCC versions that warn don't break your code.)

There are only a few minor benefits to writing a `naked` function in C + asm:

- Having the compiler emit thumb vs. ARM directives if you have code that can compile for either mode.  (Cortex-M0 is thumb-only so no benefit for your case.)
- debug info, dynamic library function size, and other metadata stuff like that.
- get the compiler to do C++ name mangling for you instead of declaring it `extern "C"`, if you were writing C++.
- You can maintain it next to some actual C code it interacts with.

Otherwise you might as well just write a separate asm file.  It still can't inline like a non-`naked` wrapper function around a GNU C Extended asm statement could.

**I'm not an ARM expert, but there's nothing wrong with the way you were using inline asm / `naked` function.**  The body of a `naked` is basically the only sane use-case for GNU C "Basic" asm (no constraints).

If you compile this with the right GCC options, GCC should emit the same directives you were using in stand-along asm.  (Although not `.cantunwind` in case that matters.)

---

[From Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A__attribute__((naked))+uint8_t+dummy(uint8_t+value)%0A%7B%0A++++asm+volatile+(%0A++++++++++++%22push+++%7Br1-r7,+lr%7D%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A+++++++++++++//+R0+contains+input+value%0A+++++++++++++//here+i+do+some+operation+on+registers+r0..r7+++++++++%0A+++++++++++++//.....%0A+++++++++++++//I+guess+result+will+be+in+the+R0+register%0A++++++++++++%22MOV+R0,+R3%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A%0A++++++++++++%22pop++++%7Br1-r7,+pc%7D%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++++++)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm541,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O2+-Wall+-mcpu%3Dcortex-m0+-mthumb+-fverbose-asm',selection:(endColumn:19,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:19,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:19,selectionStartLineNumber:29,startColumn:19,startLineNumber:29),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+5.4.1+(none)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+5.4.1+(none)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), `gcc5.4.1 -O2 -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -fverbose-asm` compiles it cleanly (no warnings).  This is the asm output, with directives unfiltered, but some manual editing to remove directives and labels I think are just clutter (including debug info):

```
        .syntax unified
        .cpu cortex-m0
        .fpu softvfp

        .text
        .global dummy
        .code   16
        .thumb_func
        .type   dummy, %function
dummy:
        .syntax divided
        push   {r1-r7, lr}
        MOV R0, R3
        pop    {r1-r7, pc}

        .thumb
        .syntax unified
        .cfi_endproc
        .size   dummy, .-dummy
```

Since you're on a thumb-only CPU you don't *need* thumb interworking via `bx lr`, but as @old timer points out: if you can leave LR untouched during your function then you can just return with `bx lr` instead of popping it back into PC.

Also note that the first arg is passed in R0, so reading R3 is reading a register that your prototype says is not an input.

---

**Moving this to a stand-alone asm file is totally fine, just as valid, and probably a better choice.  But since you asked about doing it with a `naked` function, that should also work.**

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is very useful for me. I asked the question because i was not aware about calling convention, and if i can return value through R0 register. And i was thinking that this might be the reason of the crash. Reading the answers i found that my original code was more or less fine and working. And then i found the problem in another part of my code. The code is actually doing some SPI bitbanging and it crashed because i violated some timing.